# return json data in javascript function not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, return

Im new to Ajax and im at the point that i get data.The only thing is i cant return my data i get undefine etc. Here is the code:

```
function select_aragement(arragament){
    var arrst = arragament;
    var arrsplit = arrst.split("|");
    var periode = arrsplit[0];
    var id = arrsplit[1];

    var data =$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'ajax/prijzen.php',
        data:{
            id: id,
            periode:periode
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
    return data.responseText;
}
```

In this code, `arragement` is an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.responseText` isn't available when the AJAX call is still being done. You will need to wait after the AJAX closure and use the `.done()` function to make sure the call has completed.

This will look somewhat like this:

```
$.ajax({ 
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'ajax/prijzen.php',
  data: { what: 'ever' },
  dataType: 'json'
}).done(function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Greetings back from the Netherlands!

Answer (score 1):

The response data from ajax will not be available until the ajax request is complete. So,try using like `success` as follows :

```
function select_aragement(arragament){
 var arrst = arragament;
 var arrsplit = arrst.split("|");
 var periode = arrsplit[0];
 var id = arrsplit[1];

     var data =$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'ajax/prijzen.php',
       data:{
           id: id,
          periode:periode
       },
       dataType: 'json'
       success:function(data){
         return data.responseText;
       }
    });    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bjorn is just right. Always consider waiting for your asynchronous calls being finished ;)

There are three types of callbacks: **done** (success is deprecated), **fail** (you should always do something on fail) and **always**, which is 'always' called (whether the request fails or not)

I'd suggest you to read this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/